# Circular reference between two structs with high performance

Tags: rust, cyclic-reference

I have two structs `Node` and `Communicator`. `Node` contains "business-logic" while `Communicator` contains methods for sending and receiving UDP messages. `Node` needs to call methods on `Communicator` when it wants to send messages and `Communicator` needs to call methods on `Node` when it receives a UDP message. If they are the same struct, there is no problem at all. But I want to separate them because they clearly have different responsibilities. Having it all in one struct would become unmanageable. My code looks as follows:

```
fn main() {
    use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar, Weak};
    use std::thread;


    pub struct Node {
        communicator: Option<Arc<Communicator>>
    }

    impl Node {
        pub fn new() -> Node {
            Node {
                communicator: None
            }
        }

        pub fn set_communicator(&mut self, communicator: Arc<Communicator>) {
            self.communicator = Some(communicator);
        }
    }

    pub struct Communicator {
        node: Option<Weak<Node>>
    }

    impl Communicator {
        pub fn new() -> Communicator {
            Communicator {
                node: None
            }
        }

        pub fn set_node(&mut self, node: Weak<Node>) {
            self.node = Some(node);
        }
    }



    let mut my_node = Arc::new(Node::new());
    let mut my_communicator = Arc::new(Communicator::new());

    Arc::get_mut(&mut my_node).unwrap().set_communicator(Arc::clone(&my_communicator));

    //Arc::get_mut(&mut my_communicator).unwrap().set_node(Arc::downgrade(&my_node));
}
```

My code crashes, as I predicted, if I uncomment both of the two last lines. But it is something like that I want to achieve.

I see a couple of options:

- Use `Mutex` or `RwLock` to gain interior mutability. But that gives a performance penalty.
- Use `Cell` or `RefCell`. But they are not thread-safe.
- Use `AtomicCell` from `crossbeam`. Looks like the best option so far. But what about performance?
- Use `unsafe`. But where? And how to ensure the code remains memory safe in spite of `unsafe`?

In theory I could split `Communicator` into a `Sender` and a `Receiver`, so that there would be no cyclical references. But for my program, I know I will have a similar situation in the future where this will not be possible.

It seems that since I just split a struct into two, for code-structuring reasons, and gaining no new functionality, there should be a way to do this without having to pay any performance penalty like `Mutex` would give.

Comment: Although it's not wrong, typically structs and impls for them are stored outside of functions (especially `main`) for readability and less confusion.

Comment: Have you concidered using [`MPSC`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html) or one of the [queues](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.1/crossbeam/queue/index.html) provided by the [crossbeam crate](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam)?

Comment: I have thought about using channels. When the two structs are the same, when a UDP message is received, that thread just continues to execute the "Node" code. When they are separate I guess the UDP receive thread could send a message on the channel and let the thread executing `Node` do whatever it wants to do. But then there is the overhead of another thread and having to wake it up on `tx.recv`.

Comment: *maybe*. Doen't assume it, but instead test it ;) Write some little testbenches and test different approaches. Then use the [rust testbench](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.16.0/book/benchmark-tests.html) (or use the [testbench](https://crates.io/crates/testbench) crate)  and test it. Don't assume anything about speed :)

Comment: Interesting no one mentioned your design is plain wrong. Go learn about [mediator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator) pattern. The fact you're using Rust doesn't free you from doing it right. Circular dependencies are stinky code smell... I'm pretty sure after you use it with some traits it'll become more clear what to use for real communication.

Comment: I voted "too broad" because there may be any number of solutions to problems like this one (you listed several of them), and a complete treatment of the topic could be a book in itself. In general though I would agree that you should try to eliminate the cyclic dependency before trying to make it work with `Mutex` or `RwLock`. In particular, in a single-threaded context, I don't know why `Communicator` needs to call a message on `Node` when `Node` could just poll the `Communicator`; in a multi-threaded context, I don't know why you wouldn't use channels.

Comment: The Mediator pattern looks like what I need for this. But how do I implement it in Rust? The problem that arise for me with the Mediator pattern seems to be the same like I've described here. I found [this example](https://chercher.tech/rust/mediator-design-pattern-rust). In that example the mediator owns all components, but the struct of a component has no reference to the mediator. So whenever the mediator (or something from the outside) calls a function on a component, it has the pass the mediator. So through all component methods, `&self` and the mediator have the be passed around.

Comment: If this question is too broad, should I perhaps create a new question on how to implement the mediator pattern in Rust?

Comment: I usually dislike questions like "How do I implement X pattern [in Rust]", so I wouldn't suggest it. ;-) Patterns are recurring ideas, not recipes -- you shouldn't take exactly what whoever wrote on a website and copy and paste the code into your project (unless, of course, they happen to be solving the exact problem you have). Instead, I would try to find a way to write this code *without* making the components (`Node`s in your case?) store references to the mediator (`Communicator`?). You need to eliminate the cyclic dependency, not just apply the "right pattern" (so to speak).

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a great place for open-ended design questions, so if you want help with the overall design or knowing where to start, I suggest asking on [users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org).

Comment: TBH, the open-ended discussion was caused by comments. The way the question is asked - it’s not too broad at all, it can have a specific answer (with a comment “the best solution to your problem may be something else, like using a Mediator”).